# How to disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have worked may time with Group BY in mysql but recently i have received a problem of Group By. I searched from many sites and I got the problem that its due to upgrading the mysql version in which it is enabled and in old versions it was disabled.

I won't remove it using the query but from the code. I also don't want to remove from my.cnf because when the site will live it will occure again.

so please suggest me a solution that works in codeigniter atleast. I will be thankful to you :-)

I have tried below query :

```
mysql > SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

it worked but when the server restarts the problem occurs again.

Comment: What CodeIgniter version do you use?

Comment: its 3.1.0 the version that i'm using right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Codeigniter has `stricton` option in `application/config/database.php`:

```
$db['default'] = array(
    ...
    'stricton' => FALSE, // forces 'Strict Mode' connections
    ...
);
```

Or you can disable `sql_mode` params like this:

```
$this->db->query('SET SESSION sql_mode = ""');

// ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY
$this->db->query('SET SESSION sql_mode =
                  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
                  @@sql_mode,
                  "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,", ""),
                  ",ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY", ""),
                  "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY", "")');
```

Comment: Yes i've seen that but for what they have used *stricton* i really couldn't understand. is it related to my question ?

Comment: @AftabAhmed I have fixed my answer, check it.

Comment: thanks for you response. please now finally tell me where to place this query that should run for once if ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY not enabled otherwise it should not execute so that we can increase the speed.

Comment: One of those queries must be executed after framework database connection. CodeIgniter initializes db connection in model `__construct` method. So use it in the same place in your model.

Comment: So it will run everytime when the page will be loaded. I want to run this for once so that page would be loaded in less amount of time.

Comment: If you want do it once, than the only way is disable it in mysql settings. Because code from my example I used from CodeIgniter core but with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` parameter.

Comment: Okay thanks dear :-) May Allah bless you with more knowledge. Stay Blessed. :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can run an sql query in My_controller or any Controller's  constructor function. like this

```
$sql = "SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode, 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY', ''));";
    $this->db->query($sql );
```

and this will fix the problem.